# Ploting a spectrogram of a pure sinus with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

I'm trying to get a spectogram plot of a pure sine function. Together with that i want to show a plot of the fft of that whole signal. I'm expecting the peaks to be on the same frequency since were dealing with the same signal which is stationary in time.

**code**

```
samplingFrequency = 32.
frequency = 4                           #frequency of the sinus wave
t = arange(0,20,1/samplingFrequency)    #time intervals with period 1/sampling frequency
y = cos(2*pi*frequency*t)

Y = fft.fft(y)                          #standard fft on the whole signal
frequencyAxis = fft.fftfreq(len(Y),1/samplingFrequency )          #adjusting the x axis 

#PLOTTING
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
ax1.specgram(y, Fs = samplingFrequency)
ax2.stem(frequencyAxis,Y,linefmt='r--', markerfmt='ro')
```

**plot**
[image]

The fft of the whole signal is as expected with the peak on 4. However the spectogram plots a line on 12. Ideas on where the error is?

**Update**
Was using the following versions:

- matplotlib '1.1.1'
- numpy '1.6.2'
- python 2.7.3

Comment: I can not replicate this result (Numpy 1.7.1 & matplotlib 1.2.1), as the spectrogram plots the line at 4 for me. Btw, you have a typo in your script; `freqency` instead if `frequency` in line 4.

Comment: In Python 2.7.4, numpy 1.7.1, matplotlib 1.2.1, it works properly

Comment: It worked after the update. If you are to form what you said here to an answer, i will accept it and mark the question as solved.

Comment: @Alan Did you solve it just by updating your matplotlib?

Comment: Yes, I updated both numpy and matplotlib and all works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Python 2.7.5 with numpy 1.7.1 and matplotlib 1.2.1 your code works exactly as expected. Try updating both your numpy and matplotlib installations to the most recent versions.